Failed To Read Access Token From JWT
I'm just upgraded from Keycloak 22 to 25;
I can't get the userinfo although I tried all the suggestions:

Realm Frontend should point to: http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm  --> Still not working
Add the 'openid' scope to the default clients scopes --> Still not working
Change the keycloak url in the react native app to point to: http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm  --> Still not working.

Can you please assist:
I'm using React Native as the frontend app. To fetch the user info, I'm using this method:
    const getUserInfo = await fetchUserInfoAsync(tokenResult, discoveryResult!);

The error I get from the keycloak's logs is:
2024-07-30 22:52:33 2024-07-31 05:52:33,095 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-4) type="USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR", realmId="a8f79f64-1833-4832-9b3a-079763cb6fc3", realmName="myrealm", clientId="null", userId="null", ipAddress="172.17.0.1", error="invalid_token", reason="Failed to read access token from JWT", auth_method="validate_access_token"



The error I get from the React Native app is at line 42 in Fetch.js:
 // Fix a problem with React Native `URL` causing a trailing slash to be added.

    const correctedUrl = url.toString().replace(/\/$/, '');
    const response = await fetch(correctedUrl, request); ---> (error here: 401 Unauthorized)
    const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
    if (isJsonDataType || contentType?.includes('application/json')) {
        return response.json();
    }

Can you please assist. I've spent two days trying to figure this out.
Thanks

The issue here might be related to the token algorithm used for signing. I implemented all the steps in the discussion: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/validate-jwt-token-from-keycloak/25263/7 ; but my token is still showing the "Failed to read access token from JWT" errors. However, when I check the same token in jwt.io, I get all info and the token is marked as "Signature Verified".  The issue here is on Keycload backend. Using curl, postman or another react library yield the same 401 error and the same reason. Can I please know  what algorithm is used to sign token on the backend?

I narrow down this issue to this: if you download a fresh version of Keycloak 25, add realm and use authentication code, everything works fine. However, if you add some fields to the userprofile then the present error will show with 401 unauthorized status. So the issue narrows down to this: once fields are added to userprofile then the endpoint to get the userinfo can't decode the token from JWT and thus fail with 401 status
